# PIC Receive UART Overwritten, not reading out fast enough?

Tags: serialization, embedded, uart, pic, usart

I'm trying to read in some serial data from a MODBus master and so far have managed to get my PIC to receive data using the functions created from MCC, however when the master sends too much data I can't read it out of the UART fast enough to make room for the new data coming in.

I'm quite new to this and fairly sure I'm going over things there's obvious answers for but I'm at a loss.

Currently my test program looks like:

```
printf("Initalised\r\n\n");

int Counter = 0;
 
// Set RS485 to receive.
RXMode();
    
while(1)
{
    if(EUSART1_is_rx_ready()){
        Counter++;           

        printf("Triggered: %i \r\n\n", Counter);

        while(EUSART1_is_rx_ready()){
                // While there's something to read out
                rxData = EUSART1_Read();
                printf("eusart1RxCount: %d \r\nData: 0x%02x \r\n\n", eusart1RxCount, rxData);                
        }

    }

}
```

Sending: 0x11 0x10 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x02 0x04 0x00 0x0A 0x01 0x02 0xC6 0xF0
Produces the following output:

```
Initalised

Triggered: 1

eusart1RxCount: 5
Data: 0x11

eusart1RxCount: 11
Data: 0x01

eusart1RxCount: 10
Data: 0x02

eusart1RxCount: 9
Data: 0xc6

eusart1RxCount: 8
Data: 0xf0

eusart1RxCount: 7
Data: 0x02

eusart1RxCount: 6
Data: 0x04

eusart1RxCount: 5
Data: 0x00

eusart1RxCount: 4
Data: 0x0a

eusart1RxCount: 3
Data: 0x01

eusart1RxCount: 2
Data: 0x02

eusart1RxCount: 1
Data: 0xc6

eusart1RxCount: 0
Data: 0xf0
```

The first byte is correct, but then by the time it goes to read the 2nd byte it's actually reading the 10th byte sent, and the 3rd byte is reading the 11th byte sent....etc.

Hopefully someone can help! I've spent all day on this. Any advice is greatly appreciated, I feel like I'm on a steep learing curve here.

Comment: For each byte you receive, you print a dozen bytes or so. So this code's maximum possible sustained read speed is less than a tenth of its text write speed. Are you sure that the system's text output write speed is high enough? Have you measured it?

Comment: I've added some updates as suggested below and uploaded my code to GIT, specifically removing the print of outputs. The problem is resolved for sending up to 16 bytes by increasing the buffer size, but after that things get out of order. The GIT project also incldues a Log.txt showing what's being sent and received.

[link](https://github.com/PottyMonster/ModbusShift/tree/SerialTest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MCC generated USART driver code internally buffers the received data in a 8B (typically) ring-buffer; defined by `EUSART2_RX_BUFFER_SIZE`  in `eusart1.c`. What you are finding is that the buffered data is being overwritten, before the application loop can read it out of the buffer with `EUSART1_Read()`.

Generally, on detecting buffered RX data, `EUSART1_is_rx_ready`, you should read **all** the buffered data by repeating `EUSART1_Read`. With all the trace printing between each character read, the application isn't giving much bandwidth to processing the inbound data. This approach isn't scalable.

If the trace prints are required, then the USART RX buffer size should be increased to avoid the ring-buffer wrapping around before the data can be processed. This can be done by changing the value of `EUSART2_RX_BUFFER_SIZE`.

It is good practice to read all buffered data to a local buffer at one go, and then process it, e.g. print the locally buffered USART RX content out.

Comment: Thank you! I've looked at EUSARTx_RX_BUFFER_SIZE so many times! The trace prints were just added in to help work out what was happening. Works fine now.

Comment: I think it was getting ahead of myself. I set the RX_BUFFER_SIZE to 16, however I'm still getting data overwritted when sending around 25 of more bytes. I'm expecting to receive around 80 bytes in total.

I've set up a while loop within EUSART1_is_rx_ready which reads the EUSART1 and copies the byte to a rxData[i] array all the time there's somethign in there which seems to work ok, but I seem to need a delay (around 5ms) between EUSART1_Read's or it goes a bit crazy and thinks it's received data twice.

Comment: I'm confused tbh, I thought putting EUSART1_Read() in a loop whenever there's something in the RX buffer would be fast enough to clear it out before the next bytes come in, but apparently not.

Comment: @DanTwining Are you able to share the updated code you are still having issues with?

Comment: I've placed the code on GIT: https://github.com/PottyMonster/ModbusShift/tree/SerialTest
I'm new to GIT too but hopefully that's visible.

The code is fairly similar to my original post but without the printf outputs, and reads the data in to rxData[ByteNum] array in a loop all the time there's something in the UART.

Comment: Number of things from the code
  * `rxData` is initialised as a 15 element char array; but both `ClearRxBuff`, `PrintRXBuff` treat it as a 50 element array leading to out of bounds access. You can expect be overwriting other content in RAM here.
  * `rxData[ByteNum] = EUSART1_Read();` could be, and is likely, filling the buffer out of bounds, where `ByteNum` isn't limited. Increase the buffer sizes to hold the max message size you expect in an instance and is bound, or implement a ring-buffer.
  * `PrintRXBuff` traces the full `rxData` buffer, tracing up to `ByteNum` would be enough.

Comment: Further, the `while ... EUSART1_Read` could execute faster than it takes a for a byte to be received, this will resulting in a trace being printed per character and leading to issues as described in my answer. Reducing the trace to echo the characters received, also see comment above, could relax the need for large buffers. If your max message size is 80 char, ideally, your buffers should be able to accommodate it as a minimum.

Comment: I think I added in the changes as you suggested, but I'm still having similar issues. I've added a log showing what's been sent and recieved with my new code. It looks like around byte 16 it misses another 16 bytes, and then duplicate data gets added to the end of the rxData buffer.

Thanks for your help, it's really appreciated!

[link](https://github.com/PottyMonster/ModbusShift/blob/SerialTest/Log.txt)

Comment: The `EUSART2_RX_BUFFER_SIZE` still cannot accommodate the full message you are sending, I suggest this is set to the max message size as a minimum.

The behaviour, where your trace is repeating the content in the UART RX frame buffer is down to the eusart1.c driver maintaining a full count of received data, though the buffer can only hold 16B at a time. So a number of 16B chunks are lost to you, as the buffer is being filled fast than you can read.

You shouldn't need the 2ms delay either, this would make things worse should you attempt to send two messages in quick succession.

Comment: Thanks again! When I tried to increase the RX_BUFFER_SIZE beyond 16 before things got crazy so I thought that was a limit. For some reason I've increased it to 100 now and removed the delay and it works almost too well!  It clears the buffer out before more data is received which is great, but I was using a empty buffer as a sign that serial data receiving was complete. I've updated the GIT and Log file. I'm assuming there isn't any real way of knowing when everythign has been received other than by having a end of payload character to detect (which ModBus protocol doesn't).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229388/discussion-between-anakin-and-dan-twining).